# Key differences between the GridView, the DataList and the Repeater in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

key differences between the GridView, the DataList and the Repeater in ASP.NET?Which one better for the performance?

Comment: It has nothing to do with performance, they all do different things.  The only thing they have in common is that they work on a collection of items.